# How get rid of Port number followed by domain name like www.domainname.com:49200 instead if we type www.domainname.com in browser without port number

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-6

i am trying to Host the asp.net and silverlight application in IIS(Internet Information Service) using 49200 Port instead of Default HTTP port 80.
When i am trying to browse the application With domain name www.domainname.com it is showing not connected. When i tried it for www.domainname.com:49200 application successfully browsing. How to get rid of port number 49200 Without typing port number www.domainname.com application should browse. Please Help me How to achieve this one in IIS.
Thanks in advance experts!.

Answer (score 3):

When you type www.hostname.com, the assumed port is 80.  therefore, www.hostname.com is the same as typing www.hostname.com:80.

If you want to get rid of the 49200 on the end, you will need to do one of two things:

1. Change your site in IIS to be hosted on port 80 instead of port 49200
2. Introduce another server or a load balancer which is listening on port 80 and is rerouting the traffic to port 49200 on the other server.